# Convert hex to text issue

Tags: hex, ascii, non-ascii-characters

Why when converting this hexadecimal characters, it shown invalid or contains non ascii charatcers?!

My hex character is: DBBAF3080C28037F00004A8F98

I tried online, using java or c/c++ program but no correct convert.

Can any one help giving the corect conversion ?

Comment: What do you think the correct conversion is?

Comment: @AndrewMorton try to convert it online `dencode.com/string/hex` or any website, it gives invalid characters !!!

Comment: This hex definitely isn't valid utf-8 - are you sure it should convert to characters?

Comment: @snakecharmerb yes am sure, it is a wep password in hex

Comment: @key.m It is not meant to be interpreted as text. It is simply some bytes.

Comment: @AndrewMorton can you give me then the correct conversion, I only have the hex characters mentioned above ?! thanks !!!

Comment: @key.m There is no conversion to be done, unless you want it in decimal, in which case it is 219, 186, 243, 8, ....

Comment: @AndrewMorton the hex charachters are a wireless WEP password, but it is in hex, so if I want to connect to wifi, no way to use the hex, but instead I need the corresponding conversion, any help ?